# MySQL Doesn't Recognize Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I am creating a database where users can create a login. If they are logged in, they can submit data through a form and their data should match up to their primary key/login info if that makes sense.

There are two tables, `Login_Info` and `Numbers`. The primary key for the first table is `UserID`, and I placed `UserId` in the `Numbers` table too:

```
CREATE TABLE `Login_Info` (

`UserID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`Username` varchar(25),
`Password` varchar (25)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `Numbers` (

`UserID` int(11),
`Savings` varchar(25),
`Goal1` varchar(25),
`Goal2` varchar(25),
`Goal3` varchar(25),
`Cost1` varchar(25),
`Cost2` varchar(25),
`Cost3` varchar(25),
`Weight1` varchar(25),
`Weight2` varchar(25),
`Weight3` varchar(25),
`TotalCost` varchar(25),
`PercentRound` varchar(25)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

To make `UserID` a foreign key, I created a new attribute in the second table called `EntryNumber` as the primary key then made `UserId` the foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE `Numbers` (

`EntryNumber` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`UserID` FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Login_Info(UserID),
`Savings` varchar(25),
`Goal1` varchar(25),
`Goal2` varchar(25),
`Goal3` varchar(25),
`Cost1` varchar(25),
`Cost2` varchar(25),
`Cost3` varchar(25),
`Weight1` varchar(25),
`Weight2` varchar(25),
`Weight3` varchar(25),
`TotalCost` varchar(25),
`PercentRound` varchar(25)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Now when I try to add the database, I get a message that the syntax for FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES is incorrect. I have tried many ways to add the FK but I always get a message that the FK syntax is not correct. I am not sure what my error may be here. I would appreciate if someone could take a look and let me know what element I’m missing in creating a FK through a PK used in another table, to create a link between the two tables.

Comment: @Mike Nakis has the correct syntax, but you also need to specify the type of `Numbers.UserID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE `Numbers` (

`EntryNumber` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`UserID` int(11) not null,
`Savings` varchar(25),
`Goal1` varchar(25),
`Goal2` varchar(25),
`Goal3` varchar(25),
`Cost1` varchar(25),
`Cost2` varchar(25),
`Cost3` varchar(25),
`Weight1` varchar(25),
`Weight2` varchar(25),
`Weight3` varchar(25),
`TotalCost` varchar(25),
`PercentRound` varchar(25),

FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Login_Info(UserID) 

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: thanks, that's just what the issue was. however, when I add NOT NULL to `UserID` int(11) , the data won't submit to the database (Error querying request) but it does submit when I take away NOT NULL. It seems like the UserID is still not linked to the other table, even when the user is logged in. not sure if that is a separate issue.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the data won't submit to the database". I've been able to create the table and insert data without problems.

Answer (score 1):

In the [MySQL foreign key documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) it clearly says that the syntax is quite different from what you have written:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

So, you probably need something like this:

```
UserId INT,
FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Login_Info(UserId),
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant the OP forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change your storage engine to a compatible one like InnoDB.

In phpmyadmin you can find it in Operations tab .